# timeout on query against small table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, timeout

I'm trying to do a query that gets all the ids from a table where the column  `document(varbinary(max)) is null`.

The query always timesout, and I'm running it against a 5000-row table.

```
select ID from Invoice where Document is null
```

Im using SQL Express 2008 R2 and Sql Management Studio. Is this the right way? Am I missing something? Even if I add top 1 the query time out

Comment: That looks fine to me. Not sure why it's timing out though. Which RDBMS if I may ask?

Comment: Im using SQL Server 2008 r2 Express

Comment: Are you running this from SQL Management Studio, or from client code?

Comment: Please copy/paste the exact error message, or a screenshot.

Comment: Does **any** query work against any table in any database in that server instance via SSMS?

Comment: And also: has it always timed out on this particular table, from the start? I dare say not. Then maybe some recent change has caused the problem. I'm not sure what it can be, maybe some wild computed column expression or constraint... Maybe some logon trigger doing what it shouldn't be?

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the tables gets locked. Try clicking away from the selected Table in your interface.

What RDBMS are you using? SQLserver? Sybase? or..

Does it still time out when you do:?

```
SELECT TOP 10 ID
from Invoice where Document is null
```

Comment: Im using SQL Server 2008 r2 Express

Comment: @alenhandrobog: Try putting a `TOP` clause like I suggested, and let us know if you are still experiencing a timeout.

Comment: @alejandrobog: please edit your question to include how you're running this query. Perhaps include details about TOP not returning anything for completeness of your question.

Answer (score 1):

Do it this way, for a read-only look

```
select ID from Invoice (nolock) where Document is null
```

Comment: you seems to know about this `nolock`, do you know why table could be locked? Any good explanation?

Answer (score 1):

```
If connecting on localhost Then

    If connecting from Management Studio Then

        Try restarting SQL Server services...could be locks.
        Try restarting machine...could be locks.

    ElseIf connecting from remote app code Then

        Check if SQL Server is setup for remote connections.
        Check connection strings.
        Check seccurity privleges.
        Check log file.

    End If

Else
             Check if SQL Server is setup for remote connections
        Check connection strings.
        Check seccurity privledges.

End If
```

Comment: Im going to try restarting the service in about an hour when there is less activity. I let you know the results. Thanks

Comment: I restarted the service and same thing happens

Comment: are you able to execute any select from any table in the DB?...also try using SELECT TOP 1 to return just one row...or use a WHERE clause...if none of the above work then you many have a connection or security problem.